# How to Access SSH SERVER via GIT Bash

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm having a problem trying to access another server using GIT Bash.

Do you know the command in GIT Bash?

I have tried but it always shows the error : bad number

Comment: What exactly are you trying, and what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Yes. Please elaborate. Are you trying to manually ssh into a remote server, or is something such as `git push` failing?

Comment: git-bash sounds like the standard windows distribution of git where bash is included. There will be problem to figure out what ssh is used if putty is also involved... @gungunst what command gives you problem?

Answer (score 47):

`ssh user@server -p <port>` works, at least for me.

Comment: Default port for ssh is 22, sometimes just `ssh user@server` will work.

Comment: For me it show verification failed on ,
$ ssh sdqdev@amraelp00007488
The authenticity of host 'amraelp00007488 (10.12.209.71)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:W6eiaJQCKq7W3MqzUP3YFsSBtSJBJaq81n2ooA/HkCY.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
Host key verification failed.

Answer (score 18):

The command should be as follows if you are connecting to a remote server via SSH with a private key:

```
ssh <your-user-name>@<server-public-IP-address> -p <port-number> -i <your-local-ssh-private-key-name>
```

I log into one of my servers with something like this, consider that my ssh key is under

`/c/Users/brian` or `~/`

```
ssh brian@123.456.789 -p 2200 -i brianssh
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was looking at how to pass a different key and your answer solved this for me! `-i`